# Setting the overflow property with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

i need this function to enable vertical scrolling but not horizontal.

This doesn't works:

```
function scrollFunction() {
        // Scroll to top 
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow-y='auto';
}
```

While this does, but it enables both vertical and horizontal scrolling.

```
function scrollFunction() {
    // Scroll to top
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow='auto';
}
```

How can I specify just the overflow-y properly?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compound style properties are written in camelCase notation (the first letter is small):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflowY = "auto";
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to VisioN's answer you can use square brackets and a string to access it:

```
document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].style['overflow-y'] = "auto";
```

This is good if you don't know what the camelCase is.

Comment: Thank you too for mentioning that!